# What is the "identity pointer" before a TTypeInfo there for?

Tags: delphi, pointers, rtti, internals

If you poke around enough in Delphi internals, you'll find something strange and apparently undocumented about TTypeInfo records generated by the compiler.  If the PTypeInfo points to a TTypeInfo record at address X, at `X - 4` you'll find the next 4 bytes describe a pointer to X.  For example:

```
procedure test(info: PTypeInfo);
var
  addr: cardinal;
  ptr: PPointer;
begin
  addr := cardinal(info);
  writeln('addr: ', addr);
  dec(addr, 4);
  ptr := PPointer(addr);
  addr := cardinal(ptr^);
  writeln('addr: ', addr);
end;
```

Pass any legitimate PTypeInfo generated by the compiler into this routine, and it'll output the same address twice.  I've poked around in TypInfo.pas a little, but I don't see anything that mentions this "identity pointer" or what it's there for.  Does anyone know why this is there?  This appears to be true in every version of Delphi from at least D3 to D2010.

Comment: I assume a `var` is missing in the above code...

Comment: @Andreas: Where? I don't see any missing vars...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very simple: packages and dynamic linking.

BPLs are DLLs. DLLs are linked up through tables being patched, rather than all the code in the EXE or DLL linking against the DLL being patched (which would do great harm to sharing of read-only memory between multiple processes). To prevent the need for a reference to `TypeInfo(SomeType)` somewhere in the code, or typeinfo of an EXE or DLL, being modified when linking against the BPL, instead there's an indirection through the import table.

It's easy to see the difference when linking statically versus linking against a BPL in this program:

```
{$apptype console}
uses TypInfo, SysUtils;
type
  TFoo = class(TObject);
var
  x: PPTypeInfo;
begin
  x := GetTypeData(TypeInfo(TFoo))^.ParentInfo;
  Writeln(x^^.Name);
  Writeln(Format('x  %p', [x]));
  Writeln(Format('x^ %p', [x^]));
end.
```

On my local machine, compiled with `dcc32 test.pas`, it outputs:

```
TObject
x  00401B64
x^ 00401B68
```

But when compiled with the RTL package with `dcc32 -LUrtl test.pas`, it outputs:

```
TObject
x  004051F0
x^ 40001DA4
```

Hopefully this clears it up.

Comment: I was just going to formulate a quite similar idea. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: So that pointer has to be somewhere for the linker to do it's job, and it just happens to be placed immediately before the data it points to, when that data is in the same module, by convention?  OK, that makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mason all typeinfo fixups - pointers from one blob of typeinfo to another - are of type PPTypeInfo, not PTypeInfo, to handle the dynamic linking case. In the case of static linkage, there needs to be an intermediate pointer for the convention to work, and part of the typeinfo itself makes as much sense as any. That is to say, it's not there for the linker; it's there because of the convention, and the convention is there because of dynamic linking, which is done the way it is to maximize potential for page sharing.

Comment: Ah, so that's what PPTypeInfo is there for.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand completely what is going on, but when you have a look at for example `IsPublishedProp` in the `TypInfo` unit, you'll see that it casts the ClassInfo of the instance as a pointer to a TypeInfo structure:

```
PTypeInfo(Instance.ClassInfo)
```

When you look at the ClassInfo method, it returns a simple pointer the value of which seems related to the vmt table:

```
  Result := PPointer(Integer(Self) + vmtTypeInfo)^;
```

`vmtTypeInfo` has a value of -72. Four bytes before that at -76 is `vmtInitTable`. vmtTypeInfo is followed by FieldTable, MethodTable, DynamicTable etc.

the vmtInitTable value is used in for example `TObject.CleanupInstance` and passed to `_FinalizeRecord` as the pointer to the TypeInfo structure.

So the four bytes before the TypeInfo structure pointing to the TypeInfo structure seem to be there by design and part of the vmt structure.

**Edit**

As Mason rightly pointed out the above is a complete red herring (see comments). I am leaving the answer so others won't have to chase it down.

**Update**
To avoid confusion over variables and their addresses, I have rewritten Mason's test procedure as follows:

```
procedure test(info: PTypeInfo);
begin
  writeln('value of info       : ', cardinal(info));
  writeln('info - 4            : ', cardinal(info) - 4);
  writeln('value 4 bytes before: ', cardinal(PPointer(cardinal(info)-4)^));
end;
```

and call it with the following information:

```
procedure TryRTTIStuff;
begin
  writeln('TPersistent');
  test(TypeInfo(TPersistent));

  writeln('TTypeKind enumeration');
  test(TypeInfo(TTypeKind));

  writeln('Integer');
  test(TypeInfo(Integer));

  writeln('Nonsense');
  test(PTypeInfo($420000));
end;
```

The first three produce the results that Mason describes. I only added an extra writeln to show the pointer value for the last writeln. The last call in TryRTTIStuff is to show that when you do not pass in a pointer to a valid TypeInfo structure, you do not get the same value on the first and third writeln's for the call.

No clue yet as to what is going on with the TypeInfo. Maybe we should ask Barry Kelly as he is the author of the new D2010 RTTI so should know a lot about the old one as well...

Comment: Sorry, but you're looking at the wrong thing.  TypeInfo is unrelated to VMTs, since it can exist for non-object types as well.  The VMT contains a pointer to the class's TTypeInfo record, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Mason: You may be perfectly right, but I thought that "old-style RTTI" only supports TypeInfo on classes and enumerations? And the latter only if you do not assign specific values in the enumeration declaration. RTTI for other types didn't show up until D2010 I think (I am using D2009).

Comment: No.  Type info had to be available for any basic type that could be used in a DFM, since that's what the system was invented for: form serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Oh ok, of course. I thought the TTypeKinds were "just" the descriptors of a class' properties, but the basic types indeed have their own TypeInfo structure (I am playing with your code as I go). Pity the TypeInfo method is compiler magic isn't it...

Comment: Yeah, Barry's been known to show up on here and answer questions sometimes.  I kinda think he or Allen Bauer might be the only ones who can give a valid answer to this question. :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a linked list that happens to be in contiguous memory:)

Comment: No, because there's nothing resembling a "next pointer" in the TTypeInfo/TTypeData structures.  Interesting idea, though.